# Angular - How can I define a owl carousel callback function in a angular component.ts?

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, callback, owl-carousel

I want to make this works in typescript, but it just can't be accepted. Do you know how to make it right?

```
    let owl = ('.owl-carousel');
    owl.owlCarousel();
    // Listen to owl events:
    owl.on('initialize.owl.carousel', function(event) {
    ...
    })
```

Comment: what message you get from TS?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to install `ngx-owl-carousel`.

Follow the steps include in this link for [ngx-owl-carousel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-owl-carousel)

Comment: Hi. I have it installed. The problem here is that I want it to delay the initialize of owl gallery and I don't know how to do it. Then I've seen the documentation I get that code... but it's in jquery and not in typescrit.

Comment: Add the code in ngAfterViewInit hook of angular, and check the callbacks in the url to check the initializing of the carousel.